# RegEx leaves unwanted space behind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a list of words separated by comma. 
e.g.: `list.join(' ');`
**How do I remove a word *(variable)* using RegEx and without leaving a space behind?**

view example code:

```js
var testClasses = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className;
var classToRemove = "test3";

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = "Removing class ." + classToRemove + " from: <strong>" + testClasses + "</strong>";

var re = new RegExp(classToRemove + "\s?", "g");
testClasses = testClasses.replace(re, "");

// I ran into the same problem trying to be more specific
// var re = new RegExp("(\S+\s?)*(" + classToRemove + "\s?)(\S+\s?)*", "g");
// testClasses = testClasses.replace(re, "$1$3");


document.getElementsByTagName('p')[1].innerHTML = "becomes: <strong>" + testClasses + "</strong>" + " // which looks great on the DOM.";
console.log(testClasses);
console.log(testClasses.split(' '));
```

```html
<div class="test1 test2 test3 test4 test5"></div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>However, if you check console, the space is there. <br><strong>How do I remove this extra space?</strong> Without having to run a second replace.</p>
```

Restrictions:

- I know this could be achieved with string or array manipulation. However, I'm trying to understand RegEx.
- Only use one RegEx. Two replaces seems ugly and unnecessary.
- I can't assume there'll always be an empty space before/after the given word.

Comment: To match whitespace you need literal `\s` in the pattern. You defines an optional letter `s` with `\s?` in `new RegExp(classToRemove + "\s?", "g");`. Did you mean `new RegExp(classToRemove + "\\s?", "g");`? And perhaps, the final solution you need is `var re = new RegExp("\\s*" + classToRemove, "g");`. `"\\s*"`. Note that (`\s*`) matches zero or more whitespaces.

Comment: any amount of whitespace -> `\s*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what if the list only has the word I want to remove? It will have NO whitespace at all, so it must be optional.

Comment: *Note that (`\s*`) matches zero or more whitespaces.* Try `var re = new RegExp("\\s*" + classToRemove, "g");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works! Could you please create an more elaborate answer (not inside comments) so I can upvote your solution? Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I interest you in [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)? This API allows mutating `class` attribute through convenient methods like `.add()`, `.remove()` and `.toggle()`. This is far superior to rolling your own RegExp solution.

---

If it doesn't have to be a RegExp solution, you could try [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
'alpha bravo charlie'
  .split(' ')
  .filter(function(token) { return token !== 'alpha' })
  .join(' ');
```

---

But let's get on with solving your RegExp riddle. In a string `"alpha bravo charlie"` you want to be able to remove any of the three tokens without leaving behind any unnecessary spaces before, after or between the remaining tokens. This can be done with the help of a [negative look-ahead assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#assertions) (`x(?!y)`):

```
function removeToken(text, token) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('(\\s+(?!\\S+\\s+))?' + token + '\\s*');
  return text.replace(pattern, '');
}
```

The negative look-ahead assertion `(\s(?!\S+\s+))?` will only include the space in front of your token, if there is no space *after* the token. This way you avoid removing both spaces in case you're removing a token in the middle. The expression reads "capture one or more space characters, unless they are followed by one or more non-space characters that are followed by one or more space characters". The "non-space characters" match your token, without having to inject the token in there as well. As these leading spaces are not always there, the capture group is made optional by a trailing `?`.

To test this code, we can run all four cases:

```
var text = 'alpha bravo charlie';
var tests = {
  // <token to remove>: <resulting string>
  'alpha': 'bravo charlie',
  'bravo': 'alpha charlie',
  'charlie': 'alpha bravo',
  'delta': 'alpha bravo charlie',
};

Object.keys(tests).forEach(function(token) {
  var expected = tests[token];
  var result = removeToken(text, token);
  console.log('removed "' + token + '" got "' + result + '" which is', expected === result ? 'correct' : 'WRONG');
});
```

and that should print

```
removed "alpha" got "bravo charlie" which is correct
removed "bravo" got "alpha charlie" which is correct
removed "charlie" got "alpha bravo" which is correct
removed "delta" got "alpha bravo charlie" which is correct
```

If you expect your tokens to contain characters that have a meaning in RegExp, you'd want to [escape them](https://github.com/benjamingr/RegExp.escape/blob/master/polyfill.js).

Comment: I ran into this problem trying to get a .classList solution to IE9. So I tried creating an add/remove from .className instead. The Negative look-ahead link is a gold mine, thanks! I can now also do `'(\\s+(?=\\S+$))?' + token + '\\s*'` positive look-aheads. Thank you for the very elucidating response! Also, thanks for pointing out `RegExp.escape`

Answer (score 1):

To match whitespace you need literal `\s` in the pattern, that means a backslash and `s`. You defined an optional letter `s` with `"\s?"` in `new RegExp(classToRemove + "\s?", "g")` because in a C string literal one needs 2 backslashes to define a literal backslash.

Use

```
var re = new RegExp("\\s*" + classToRemove, "g");
```

Note that `"\\s*"` (`\s*`) matches zero or more whitespaces. Since `classToRemove` cannot contain non-word chars, it does not need regex escaping, so I am not adding that escaping code here.

If there can only be a single occurrence of a  class name, remove the `"g"` global modifier and just use `var re = new RegExp("\\s*" + classToRemove)`.

Comment: I had no idea it suddenly became a C string (my first programming language was C). Perfect explanation! Thanks!

Comment: *C string literal* is a type of string that allows escape sequences like `\n` for a newline, `\r` for carriage return, etc. When you use `/\s/`, the backslash is not treated as an escape sequence, it is a literal backslash + `s`.

Comment: What if I want to remove the first element from the list? This preceding `\\s*` doesn't help.

Comment: Why not call `.trim()` on the result? It will be less costly for performance.

Comment: trim() is a simple fix indeed.